$\epsilon$-regular almost surely
Let $G\sim G(n,p)$ and $\lambda>0$ a fixed constant. Let $V_n$ be the vertex set of $G$. Show that:
For all disjoint $A_n,B_n\subset V_n$ with $|A|,|B|\geq n\lambda$, $(A_n,B_n)$ is $\epsilon$-regular.
has probability $1-o(1)$ for sufficiently large $n$.
My Attempts
I don't know how to deal with the $\epsilon-$regular condition, namely '$|d(A,B)-d(X,Y)|<\epsilon$ for all $X\subset A,Y\subset B$ with $|X|>\epsilon |A|,|Y|>\epsilon|B|$' in a probabilistic manner.
I have tried a strengthened version: $d(A, B),d(X, Y)\in (p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ but failed to proceed with the calculation.
From
The problem was the last problem of our Qual exams several years ago (possibly not increasing in difficulty).

For a given disjoint pair $(X,Y)$, the number of edges $e(X,Y)$ is binomial with mean $\mu = p |X||Y|$. By a Chernoff bound, $e(X,Y)$ is within the interval $[(1-\epsilon/2)/\mu, (1+\epsilon/2)/\mu]$, and therefore $d(X,Y)$ is within the interval $[(1 -\epsilon/2)p, (1+\epsilon/2)p]$, except with probability at most
$$
    2 \exp(- \epsilon^2 p |X||Y|/12).
$$
Provided that both $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are at least $\epsilon \lambda n$, this is $e^{-\Omega(n^2)}$, and $e^{\Omega(n^2)}$ grows much faster than $3^n$: an upper bound on the number of disjoint pairs $(X,Y)$. Therefore, for sufficiently large $n$ (in terms of $p, \lambda, \epsilon$), we have $d(X,Y) \in [(1 -\epsilon/2)p, (1+\epsilon/2)p] \subseteq [p - \epsilon/2, p + \epsilon/2]$ with high probability.
If this holds, then for any disjoint pair $(A,B)$ with $|A|$ and $|B|$ at least $\lambda n$, and for any subsets $X \subseteq A$ and $Y \subseteq B$ with $|X| \ge \epsilon |A|$ and $Y \ge \epsilon |B|$, the bound above applies to both $(A,B)$ and $(X,Y)$. Since both $d(X,Y)$ and $d(A,B)$ are with $\epsilon/2$ of $p$, they are within $\epsilon$ of each other.
